# Ordering Controls inside FlowLayoutpanel

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel` that is being filled at runtime with controls of the type `MasterMeter` (and controls inheriting from MasterMeter). This is your standard `Usercontrol`. Each of those controls has a property `ErrorTime`. This value keeps the duration of the current error or alert.

```
 Datetime? ErrorTime {get; set;}
```

I'm currently trying to order the controls using the `bubblesort-method` based on the duration of the error (descending).  Right now I was wondering is there a faster/more performant/more reliable way to do this?

If not, is there another container i could be using? 
It needs to have the following caracteristics:

- Amount of items may vary
- Amount of items at runtime may change from 0 to 100 (never had more than 100 errors before...)
- Must be able to contain usercontrols

**Current Code (that won't sort)**

I'm using a 1D-Array to keep it simple (in reality its a jagged Array).
Note: The possibilty of `NULL` values

```
MasterMeter[] meterList = {new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = null },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(37) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(53) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = null },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-17) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) },
                           new MasterMeter() { ErrorTime = null }
                          };
```

I'm `Bubblesorting` as follows:

```
        for (int outer = 0; outer < meterList.Count(); outer++)
        {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < (meterList.Count() - 1); inner++)
            {
                if (meterList[inner].ErrorTime > meterList[inner + 1].ErrorTime)
                {
                    var temp = meterList[inner + 1];
                    meterList[inner + 1] = meterList[inner];
                    meterList[inner] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

My ouput result (Using `Console.Writeline`):

```
        foreach (MasterMeter meterlist in meterList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(meterlist.ErrorTime);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

But my array still isn't sorted. What is going wrong here?

Comment: You should show your sorting code.

Comment: Done! thnx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide what to do with those null values in your list since it does interfere with your bubble sort:

```
if (!meterList[inner].ErrorTime.HasValue || 
    meterList[inner].ErrorTime > meterList[inner + 1].ErrorTime) {
```

As far as re-ordering the controls in the FlowLayoutPanel, that code was missing from your post, but in general, you would use the `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex` method to re-order your controls.

Comment: Thats the reason why i'm searching for an alternative to the bubblesort. I could set  the null values to `DateTime.MinValue`, but i'm not convinced that its the way to go. Your code has given me an idea though. I could just filter out the `null`values and set them into the first position.

Answer (score 0):

I just read this and I am not sure the answer really convinced, and we can quietly bet that many people in the next ten years will have controls to order in FlowLayoutPanels.

I had the problem of a FlowLayoutPanel not showing the controls in the order I wanted.

As I clear the controls at each modification, before loading them again from a TableAdapter (to a DataSet), all I had to do was to correct the query of the TableAdapter, so that it fills the DataSet in the order I want.

Then, the controls of the FlowLayoutPanel are loaded in the order of the DataSet.

In the proposals here I saw SetChildIndex : this means you have to browse through the collection of controls in the FlowLayoutPanel, and give each the index you want it to have.

It would be interesting to operate both, to compare the time it takes. But one point has been left unsaid : what method to use to determine each control's index, when avoiding to clear the controls to fill them again.

In this case I guess you have to pay attention that your code is readable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34829406)